# Why doesn't my async function combine with a callback to produce a result?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

My code is as follows:

```
myAsync().then((text) => {
    console.log(text);
});

async function myAsync() {
    cbFunction("Hello world ", function(result) {
        return result;
    });
}

function cbFunction(myString, callback) {
    callback(myString + "test");
}
```

I'm expecting "Hello world test"

Instead, I get "undefined".

Why doesn't the above code work?

Comment: Why do you expect `async function`s to combine with callbacks? Their only feature is to `await` promises, which you are not doing here.

Answer (score 1):

`myAsync` has no `return` statement. Normally this would mean it returns `undefined`, but since it is `async`, it returns a Promise, which resolves immediately, with no data.

If you want to return a promise which resolves with the data from `cbFunctin` then you need to **explicitly** return that Promise and call `resolve(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    myAsync().then((text) => {
        console.log(text);
    });
    
    function myAsync() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cbFunction("Hello world ", function (result) {
                resolve(result);
            });
        })
    
    }
    
    function cbFunction(myString, callback) {
        callback(myString + "test");
    }
```

will get you the result you need. You need to return a promise from `myAsync` and resolve a result.

You need to learn how promises work before being able to use the async/await keywords.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

You don't need to declare a function async if there is no await keyword in its body, but you might need to return a promise from a function if you want to use the await keyword